# what is the key shortcut to run console.log() in jsbin?

Tags: console.log, jsbin

I want to know what is the key shortcut for console.log() in jsbin?

Is there a combination of keys on a keyboard to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found it, if anyone ever will need it, it's type "cl" letters together and press TAB.

Cheers